# Facebook login Permission API

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an iPhone App that uses Facebook Login and I have a particular question. When the user is asked:

> "XYZ App would like to post publicly to Facebook for you".

Who should be able to see these posts?

- Public
- Friends
- Only Me

The question is this. Is it is possible to see what selection was made by the user whether he selected Public, Friends or Only Me?

Any insights or thoughts on this, is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

No, an application can not view what privacy settings the user has enabled for the application.

Comment: Considering their API it is possible.

Comment: Hi Oleg. Can you send a direct link, please? So, i can read more about it. Couldn't find anything related to this. Thanks

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment below his answer, it is impossible to retrieve this because there is no privacy activity parameters for specific users available through the application object in the graph API.  I think he misunderstood you were looking for specific user privacy settings and not those set for the application itself.

Answer (score 1):

Hi this is quite tricky question.

But it takes some time to investigate Facebook [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/app) and that have parameter to describe privacy of the app.They have object app that contains all information that you need. Object parameter is `auth_referral_default_activity_privacy`.

Comment: Actually, this is wrong.  That parameter is only detectable by an application using an app access token.  He wants to know whether a specific user has selected `Public`, `Friends`, or `Only Me` in the login dialog for specific actions.  That would require looking up a user ID and in the application object of the Graph there is no option to do so.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot get the exact info but you can have a clue if the post was either deleted or it was not set to be shared to public

**How?**

You can get a Graph call with a specific post id. If it returns an error, either the post was deleted or was not shared to public.

However, you cannot retrieve any exact info about users' sharing preferences (Public - Friends - Only Me)

Hope this helps :)